# Can't change value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have some code that by looking at it should work perfectly.

```
def upc_dict_to_pandas_dataframe(upc_dict):
    #This could be done in fewer lines but I split them for debugging purposes
    d = upc_dict.items()
    d = list(d)
    d = [list(i) for i in d]

    for i in range(len(d)):
        d[i] = np.array(d[i], dtype=object)
        d[i] = np.hstack(d[i])
        x = int(d[i][3])
        d[i][3] = x
```

The last line, d[i][3] = x does not assign x to d[i][3]. Its original type is a numpy string and I'm trying to replace it with its integer form. However, it seems like it just skips the assignment line altogether. I even tried it in debug mode. I watched it convert the string digit to an integer. But no change is ever made to d[i][3].

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is the value of d after d =[list(i) for i in d],

```
<class 'list'>: [['B01A8L6KKO', ['873124006834', 'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL', 4408]], ['B00L59D9HG', ['045496891503', 'Nintendo 3DS AC Adapter', 148]], ['B00ND0EBP4', ['873124005110', 'HORI Retro Zelda Hard Pouch for Nintendo 3DS XL - Zelda Version Edition', 4403]], ['B01MSHC8WT', ['859986005680', 'Tend Insights John Deere 100 Indoor Wi-Fi Camera', 16007]], ['B07CFLK37X', ['859986005291', 'Lynx Indoor/Outdoor Pro HD Wifi Camera', -1]], ['B076ZWVR2R', ['859986005376', 'Lynx Solar Weatherproof Outdoor WiFi Surveillance Camera with Solar Panel, Facial Recognition, Night Vision, White', 23570]], ['B0716ZNTKS', ['859986005857', 'Tend Insights Minion Cam HD Wi-Fi Camera (Despicable Me 3', 17726]], ['B00MOVY01I', ['853376004284', 'Rocksteady XS Extra Battery and Charger', -1]]]
 _len_ = 8
```

Comment: It would help if you showed what `d` is, originally, and possibly at several steps along the way.  It appears to be a list of lists, but it's less what the inner lists contain.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on without seeing how you call the function.

Comment: @hpaulj. It seems to be a dictionary, turned into a two-column list. No less confusing.

Comment: It really doesn't look like numpy has any purpose here. Could you please explain what you're doing conceptually?

Comment: If `array(['1', '100', '021'], dtype='<U3')`, not amount of assignment will change it to `array([1, 100, 21])`.  The `dtype` remains `U3`, string

Comment: I am using numpy to flatten a list of lists. I have added some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to call `d[i][3]` which appears to be a nested list and use hstack, you need the `d[i]` list to be in a nested list. You can read more at  [numpy hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

Hence `list(np.hstack(d[i]))` converts the array into a nested list form. 
You can perform by yourself a simple script and can see that `np.array()` does not actually return a nested list form because it is already itself in an array form

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
print(np.array(a))

# outputs [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Oh I see. So the contents within d[i] have to have a list holding them in order to flatten it. Thank you for clearing this up! Very strange exception but now I know :)

Answer (score 1):

With the `d` you added:

```
In [28]: d[0]                                                                                                
Out[28]: 
['B01A8L6KKO',
 ['873124006834',
  'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
  4408]]
In [29]: np.array(d[0], object)                                                                              
Out[29]: 
array(['B01A8L6KKO',
       list(['873124006834', 'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL', 4408])],
      dtype=object)
In [30]: np.hstack(np.array(d[0], object))                                                                   
Out[30]: 
array(['B01A8L6KKO', '873124006834',
       'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
       '4408'], dtype='<U64')
```

While you created an object dtype array from `d[0]`, the `hstack` created a string dtype array.

```
In [31]: np.hstack(np.array(d[0], object))[3]                                                                
Out[31]: '4408'
```

Anything assigned to this array will be turned into a string.

```
In [34]: x = np.hstack(np.array(d[0], object))                                                               
In [35]: x[3] = 123                                                                                          
In [36]: x                                                                                                   
Out[36]: 
array(['B01A8L6KKO', '873124006834',
       'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
       '123'], dtype='<U64')
```

But a list does not have the common dtype constraint, so elements can be changed into integers:

```
In [37]: x = list(np.hstack(np.array(d[0], object)))                                                         
In [38]: x[3] = 123                                                                                          
In [39]: x                                                                                                   
Out[39]: 
['B01A8L6KKO',
 '873124006834',
 'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
 123]
```

`hstack` makes sure all inputs are arrays before passing them to `concatenate`:

```
In [49]: [np.atleast_1d(x) for x in d[0]]                                                                    
Out[49]: 
[array(['B01A8L6KKO'], dtype='<U10'), array(['873124006834',
        'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
        '4408'], dtype='<U64')]
```

This explains why the result of `hstack` is a string dtype.  The `np.array(d[0], object)` step is not needed.

An alternative to the `list()` wrapper is to convert the string dtype to object type:

```
In [52]: x = np.hstack(d[0]).astype(object)                                                                  
In [53]: x[3] = 123                                                                                          
In [54]: x                                                                                                   
Out[54]: 
array(['B01A8L6KKO', '873124006834',
       'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
       123], dtype=object)
```

`tolist` is usually better for making a list from an array, though it doesn't make much of a difference here: `np.hstack(d[0]).tolist()`

Another way of flattening the list is:

```
In [62]: x = np.hstack([np.array(j, object) for j in d[0]])                                                  
In [63]: x                                                                                                   
Out[63]: 
array(['B01A8L6KKO', '873124006834',
       'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
       4408], dtype=object)
```

`x[3]` remains an integer.

But you could also flatten the lists directly (since they all consist of a string and a list):

```
In [66]: [d[0][0], *d[0][1]]                                                                                 
Out[66]: 
['B01A8L6KKO',
 '873124006834',
 'HORI Premium Protector - Pikachu Edition for Nintendo New 2DS XL',
 4408]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a quick fix:

Change this line:

```
d[i] = np.hstack(d[i])
```

to this:

```
d[i] = list(np.hstack(d[i]))
```

I figured the problem was numpy specific. I'm still curious as to the reason it doesn't work with numpy.